# Upward Moving Cable Car

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, equations-of-motion

> A $1500$ kg cable car moves vertically by means of a cable that connects the ground and the top of the hill. What is the tension in the supporting (massless) cable when the cab, originally moving downward at a speed of $9.0$ m/s, is brought to rest with constant acceleration in a distance of $38$ m?

I tried to use the kinematic equations for constant acceleration:

$$\Delta y = \frac{1}{2} \left(v + v_0\right)t$$
gives $-76 = vt + 9t$,

$$v=v_0 + at$$
gives $v = 9 + a_y t$.

Substituting $v=9 + a_y t$ into the former equation and solving the quadratic gives us $t = \frac{-9 -\sqrt{5}}{a_y}$.

Now we use $\Delta y= v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2$ to get:
$$a_y = \frac{-9\sqrt{5} - 5}{76}$$.

Newton's second law of motion tells us that:

$$F_{net,y} = ma_y $$
$$T - F_g = ma_y$$
$$T = m(a_y + g) \approx 14214.095 N$$

But the solution gives $T = 1.6 \times 10^4$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: I don't have the solution with me, because I took it from "The Principles Of Physics 10ed", which only supplied answers (to specific problems), and I really want to know what mistake I made. I'm self studying, because I like physics. If Physics.SE can't answer my question, how do I find out what i did wrong? I checked my solution again too, I didn't notice anything wrong. This is NOT meant as a homework problem. Please co-operate with me here.

Comment: Hi lil' mathematician - here at Physics SE we prefer not to handle questions where you're just asking what you did wrong. That's just how we have decided to define our scope. You could edit your question to ask about some specific concept that confused you, or you might want to look for [another site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/391) that does handle the type of question you're currently asking.